# OrangeHRM - Delete a table using phpAdmin

Tags: orangehrm

So I want to delete a table from orangehrm database and I'm using phpAdmin but when I do delete to the table that I want, when I go to my site I don't see any difference.

Missing something?

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to be more clear about what the table contains and what change you expect to see on your web site. I expect that if you remove a table from your database, that your application will simply stop working because it's trying to access a table that doesn't exist anymore. Are you trying to access OrangeHRM or your own custom application? Can you explain your situation a bit further?

Comment: I already solve my problem, thanks anyway.

I had the table ohrm_menu_item and wanted to erase some fields but I realized that for that I must to erase some fields of other tables also.